# How to add name of element to custom javax validation message

Tags: java, spring, validation

In my form I am using `javax.validation`

```
@Size(max = 10, min = 9)
String myField;
```

and in ValidationMessages.properties I have defined my custom message:

```
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message = Size should be between {min} and {max}
```

but now I want to include name of field something like `Size of {field} should be between {min} and {max}`

is there a possibility to add name of field using this property file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
myfield.size.message = myField should be between {min} and {max}
```

And change:

```
@Size(max = 10, min = 9)
String myField;
```

to

```
@Size(max = 10, min = 9, message = "{myfield.size.message}")
String myField;
```

or

```
message.size=should be between {min} and {max}

@Size(max = 10, min = 9, message = "myfield {message.size}")
String myField;
```

Comment: man I ask how to do this with properties file. I have about 1000 fields with this validation and I really dont want rewrite this. I need some global sollution